# Create a function which takes a list as an argument and keeps only the numbers that are greater than 5

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements, append

I am trying to create a function that takes a list as an argument and keeps only the numbers that are greater than 5 by creating a new empty list inside the function and only append it with numbers that are greater than five, looping over the given one. However, append does not return anything or it returns None.

```
lst = [[0, 1, 5, 6, 9], [5, 5, 5, 5], [42, 1337], [-100, 100]]

def more_than_five(lst):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i > 5:
      result.append(i)
  return result


Output should be (individually. not as one list):

[6,9]
[]
[42, 1337]
[100]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double comprehension to iterate over a list of lists:

```
def more_than_five(lst):
    return [[i for i in l if i > 5] for l in lst]
print(more_than_five(lst))

# Output
[[6, 9], [], [42, 1337], [100]]
```

Without a comprehension:

```
def more_than_five(lst):
    result = []
    for j, l in enumerate(lst):
        result.append([])
        for i in l:
            if i > 5:
                result[j].append(i)
    return result
print(more_than_five(lst))

# Output
[[6, 9], [], [42, 1337], [100]]
```

**Update**: If your function only processes one list at a time:

```
def more_than_five(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if i > 5]

print(more_than_five(lst[0]))
print(more_than_five(lst[1]))
# and so on
```

Or:

```
def more_than_five(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        if i > 5:
            result.append(i)
    return result

print(more_than_five(lst[0]))
print(more_than_five(lst[1]))
# and so on
```

Output:

```
[6, 9]
[]
[42, 1337]
[100]
```

Comment: Your function worked and gave the correct Output as you have given! Thanks. However, I apologize since I did not make the output clear. The Output should have individual results for example: [6, 9].  It should not be in one unified list. 

Thank you for the effort. Happy New Years bruv!

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much!! I am still a newbie at python and I am still learning. Thank you for the patience, effort, and time! Cheers!